# "Compare with / Latest from repository" color change

Tags: colors, background, aptana

I installed Aptana Studio 3 eclipse plugin which totaly changed all default colors. After uninstalation of the plugin, in view for comparing changes from files on SVN - "Compare with / Latest from repository" still remains black background for sections which are different, comments and line numbers. Restoring setting and colors to default in "window / preferences / general" does not work. I tried also to manualy delete all folders containing "aptana" in the name from workspace. This also did not help. Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same issue.  You have to reinstall Aptana, go to Preferences -> Aptana  Studio (or whatever it is) -> Themes and pick Aptana Studio 2.x, which uses a white background and black foreground.

That preference pane goes away once you uninstall it unfortunately.  Kind of a stupid thing for them to change in that plugin, but I guess being edgy is more important than being consistent :)